# Jasper Report acess to data paramenter type JRDataSource

Tags: jasper-reports

instead of passing 20-30 parameters, I want to pass a JRDataSource parameter (ds) with the required fields. The problem is to access these fields. There is a function - getFieldValue into which you need to pass a JRField object, but I can't figure out how to do it. I will be grateful for any help

$P{ds}.getFieldValue (new JRField (???))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.